# NSLocalizedDescription=Expected status code in (200-299), got 422}

Tags: ios, objective-c, request, restkit

I'm trying to make a  ad post . I Set everything up as I thought it would be right however when I click the boson "cadastrar anuncio" it returns this error "got 422". already researched about the error however could not fix at all.
someone here has gone through this?

this is my web service

```
#import "JVWebService.h"
#import <RestKit/RestKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "JVUtils.h"
#import "Ads.h"

static NSString *kServerURL = @"http://localhost:3000";

@interface JVWebService ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) RKObjectManager *restKitObjectManager;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *adAttributes;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *postAdAttributes;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *userAttributes;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *postUserAttributes;
@end

#define kSuccessStatusCode RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)

@implementation JVWebService

+ (instancetype)sharedService {
    static JVWebService *sharedService = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedService = [[self alloc] init];

        [AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager].enabled = YES;
        sharedService.restKitObjectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kServerURL]];
        [sharedService.restKitObjectManager.HTTPClient setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:[[[AppDelegate sharedDelegate] currentUser] email]
                                                                                 password:[[[AppDelegate sharedDelegate] currentUser] password]];
    });
    return sharedService;
}

#pragma mark - User

- (void)getUserForEmail:(NSString *)email andPassword:(NSString *)password {
    RKObjectMapping *objectMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:User.class];
    [objectMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:self.userAttributes];

    RKObjectMapping *requestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
    [requestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:self.postUserAttributes];

    NSString *path = @"/users/sign_in.json";

    RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:requestMapping
                                                                                   objectClass:User.class
                                                                                   rootKeyPath:@"user"
                                                                                        method:RKRequestMethodAny];
    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:objectMapping
                                                                                            method:RKRequestMethodAny
                                                                                       pathPattern:path
                                                                                           keyPath:@"user"
                                                                                       statusCodes:kSuccessStatusCode];
    [self.restKitObjectManager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
    [self.restKitObjectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];

    User *user = [User new];
    user.email = email;
    user.password = password;

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString] forKey:@"authencity_token"];
    NSDictionary *params = @{@"authenticity_token" : [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"authencity_token"]};

    [self.restKitObjectManager.HTTPClient setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:email password:password];
    [self.restKitObjectManager postObject:user path:path parameters:params success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation,
                                                                                     RKMappingResult *result){
        User *user = (User *)result.array.firstObject;
        user.password = password;
        [[AppDelegate sharedDelegate] login:user];

        [[AppDelegate sharedDelegate] setLoggedViaFacebook:NO];

        if ([self.serviceDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(successfulRequestDidReturnObject:)])
            [self.serviceDelegate successfulRequestDidReturnObject:user];

    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){
        RKLogError(@"Operation failed with error: %@", error);

        if ([self.serviceDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(requestDidFailWithError:)])
            [self.serviceDelegate requestDidFailWithError:error];
    }];

    [self.restKitObjectManager removeResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];


    }





- (void)postAd:(Ads *)ad {
    NSString *path = @"/ads.json";

    RKObjectMapping *objectMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:Ads.class];
    [objectMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:self.adAttributes];

    RKObjectMapping *requestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
    [requestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:self.postAdAttributes];

    RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:requestMapping
                                                                                   objectClass:Ads.class
                                                                                   rootKeyPath:@"ad"
                                                                                        method:RKRequestMethodAny];
    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:objectMapping
                                                                                            method:RKRequestMethodAny
                                                                                       pathPattern:path
                                                                                           keyPath:@"ad"
                                                                                       statusCodes:kSuccessStatusCode];

    [self.restKitObjectManager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
    [self.restKitObjectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];

    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [self.restKitObjectManager multipartFormRequestWithObject:ad method:RKRequestMethodPOST path:path parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

//        NSArray *photosArray = ad.photos[0];
//        for(int i = 0; i < photosArray.count; i++) {
//            
//            NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ad[photos_attributes][%i][picture]", i];
//            NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"photo%i.jpg", i];
//            [formData appendPartWithFileData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(photosArray[i])
//                                        name:name
//                                    fileName:fileName
//                                    mimeType:@"image/jpg"];
//        }
    }];

    RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [self.restKitObjectManager objectRequestOperationWithRequest:urlRequest
                                                                                               success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *result) {
                                                                                                   if ([self.serviceDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(successfulRequestDidReturnObject:)])
                                                                                                       [self.serviceDelegate successfulRequestDidReturnObject:nil];

                                                                                               } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                                                                                   if ([self.serviceDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(requestDidFailWithError:)])
                                                                                                       [self.serviceDelegate requestDidFailWithError:error];
                                                                                               }];
    [self.restKitObjectManager enqueueObjectRequestOperation:operation];

    [self.restKitObjectManager removeRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
    [self.restKitObjectManager removeResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
}



- (NSDictionary *)adAttributes {
    return @{
             @"id" : @"_id",
             @"title" : @"title",
             @"price" : @"price",
             @"local" : @"local",
             @"description" : @"especification"
//             @"categories" : @"categories",
//             @"photos" : @"photos",
//             @"latitude" : @"latitude",
//             @"longitude" : @"longitude"
             };
}

- (NSDictionary *)postAdAttributes {
    return @{
             @"_id" : @"id",
             @"title" : @"title",
             @"price" : @"price",
             @"local" : @"local",
             @"especification" : @"description"
//             @"categories" : @"category_ids",
//             @"user_id" : @"user_id",
//             @"latitude" : @"latitude",
//             @"longitude" : @"longitude"
             };
}

- (NSDictionary *)userAttributes {
    return @{
             @"id" : @"_id",
             @"email" : @"email",
             @"name" : @"name",
             @"avatar" : @"profileImageUrl",
             @"phone" : @"phone",
             @"password" : @"password",
             @"contact_pref" : @"communicationPreference",
             @"products_alerts" : @"productsAlerts"
             };
}

- (NSDictionary *)postUserAttributes {
    return @{
             @"_id" : @"id",
             @"email" : @"email",
             @"name" : @"name",
             @"phone" : @"phone",
             @"password" : @"password",
             @"password" : @"password_confirmation",
             @"communicationPreference" : @"contact_pref"
             };
}
@end
```

this is my NewAdViewController:

```
#import "NewAdViewController.h"
#import "Ads.h"
#import "JVUtils.h"
#import "JVWebService.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface NewAdViewController ()

@end

@implementation NewAdViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (IBAction)signUp:(id)sender {


    if (self.titleField.text.length <= 0) {
        [JVUtils showMessage:@"Falta algo ae eem =D =D fdp." withTitle:@"Opa!"];
    } else if (self.priceField.text.length <= 0) {
        [JVUtils showMessage:@"Falta algo ae eem =D =D fdp" withTitle:@"Opa!"];
    } else if (self.localField.text.length <= 0) {
        [JVUtils showMessage:@"Falta algo ae eem =D =D fdp" withTitle:@"Opa!"];
    } else if (self.descriptionField.text.length <= 0) {
        [JVUtils showMessage:@"Falta algo ae eem =D =D fdp" withTitle:@"Opa!"];
    } else {
            Ads *newAd = [Ads new];
            newAd.title = self.titleField.text;
            newAd.price = self.priceField.text;
            newAd.local = self.localField.text;
            newAd.especification = self.descriptionField.text;


            [[JVWebService sharedService] setServiceDelegate:self];
            [[JVWebService sharedService] postAd:newAd];

        }
    }


- (void)successfulRequestDidReturnObject:(NSObject *)object {

    [JVUtils showMessage:@"Anuncio cadastrado =D" withTitle:@"hadoukeeeen !"];

    [[AppDelegate sharedDelegate] setCurrentUser:(User *)object];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];


}

- (void)requestDidFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

    [JVUtils showMessage:error.localizedDescription withTitle:@"Errohue"];
}


-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
}





@end
```

Here is the detail from the server log

> Started POST "/ads.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-03 18:06:15 -0300
>   Processing by AdsController#create as JSON Parameters:
>   {"ad"=>{"description"=>"ewewe", "id"=>"", "local"=>"ew",
>   "price"=>"25", "title"=>"titulp"}} User Load (0.6ms) SELECT users.*
>   FROM users WHERE users.id = 2 ORDER BY users.id ASC LIMIT 1
>   Unpermitted parameters: id (0.2ms) BEGIN (0.6ms) ROLLBACK Completed
>   422 Unprocessable Entity in 10ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 1.4ms)

Comment: 422 indicates that your data was incorrect in some way - you should check your server logs to see if any more information is available there. Perhaps the password doesn't meet complexity requirements?

Comment: I'm not adding an object that uses password. I'm registering a simple announcement containing description and price title. as a sales application no. I used a similar method with my registration of users. I think this is the problem talves but not seem to find a way to resolve.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise -  you have posted a lot of code - I saw the first post operation which was the user.  In future it is best to simplify your question to only include  the *relevant* code, however my advice is still valid - 422 indicates the server wasn't happy with the data you sent.  You need to examine the values you are sending and look for more detail on the server logs

Comment: Started POST "/ads.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-03 18:06:15 -0300
Processing by AdsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"ad"=>{"description"=>"ewewe", "id"=>"", "local"=>"ew", "price"=>"25", "title"=>"titulp"}}
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 2 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
Unpermitted parameters: id
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.6ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 10ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 1.4ms)

Comment: This is the response from the server. you can understand something? What do I could understand not helped me a lot so far.

Comment: So you can see that `id` is empty and you have an error `Unpermitted parameters: id` - so you need to determine why that is and supply a value for `id`

Comment: I Got You. Thank you very much. You helped a lot !!! Good luck here on the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Status code 422 indicates that your data was incorrect in some way - the request was well formed but the data couldn't be processed.

Looking at the log from the server you can see that `id` is empty and there is an error message `Unpermitted parameters: id`

You need to determine why id is empty and correct this before you send a request.